# Javascript Object Move and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning how to code javascript, please do not reply that this can be done by using someone else's code that already exists. I am doing this to learn.

I have a situation whereby the below CSS and HTML code:

CSS:

```
    div.miniblock {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: thin dotted #CCCCCC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
        position: relative;
}
div.miniblock_unsaved {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #55AAAA;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: thin dotted #000;
    color: #000;
    padding: 2px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
        position: relative;
}
div.dropinto {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #575757;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: thin dotted #AAAAAA;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px;
        margin: 5px;
}
div.dropinto_over {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: thin dotted #000000;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 2px;
        margin: 5px;
}
div.moving {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: thin dotted #000000;
    color: #000000;
    z-index:1;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 5px;        
        cursor: move;
}
div.OPAQUE {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000000;
        opacity: 0.5;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_side[3]" VALUE="" ID="block_side0">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_order[3]" VALUE="" ID="block_order0">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_side[4]" VALUE="" ID="block_side1">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_order[4]" VALUE="" ID="block_order1">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_side[5]" VALUE="" ID="block_side2">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_order[5]" VALUE="" ID="block_order2">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_side[6]" VALUE="" ID="block_side3">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_order[6]" VALUE="" ID="block_order3">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_side[2]" VALUE="L" ID="block_side=4">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_order[2]" VALUE="1" ID="block_order4">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_side[1]" VALUE="L" ID="block_side=5">

        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="block_order[1]" VALUE="2" ID="block_order5">
<DIV CLASS="OPAQUE" ID="instruct"></DIV>Set your preferences for the blocks of information and their display location here.<TABLE height="100%" width="100%"><TR ><TH COLSPAN="2">Assigned Blocks</TH></TR><TR ><TD COLSPAN="2">Here are the blocks that are currently displayed during your experience.</TD></TR><TR ><TD WIDTH="50%" VALIGN="TOP"><DIV CLASS="dropinto" ID="leftblocks" SLOT="L">Left Blocks<div onmousedown="grabobj(4)" onmousemove="dragobj(4)" onmouseup="dropobj(4)" id="4" name="2" class="miniblock">Quick Links [2]</div><div onmousedown="grabobj(5)" onmousemove="dragobj(5)" onmouseup="dropobj(5)" id="5" name="1" class="miniblock">Session Information [1]</div></DIV></TD><TD WIDTH="50%" VALIGN="TOP"><DIV CLASS="dropinto" ID="rightblocks" SLOT="L">Right Blocks</DIV></TD></TR><TR ><TH COLSPAN="2">Unassigned Blocks</TH></TR><TR ><TD COLSPAN="2" ID="unassigned_blocks">Here are the blocks that are not currently displayed during your experience.<div onmousedown="grabobj(0)" onmousemove="dragobj(0)" onmouseup="dropobj(0)" id="0" name="3" class="miniblock">Another Block [3]</div><div onmousedown="grabobj(1)" onmousemove="dragobj(1)" onmouseup="dropobj(1)" id="1" name="4" class="miniblock">And Another [4]</div><div onmousedown="grabobj(2)" onmousemove="dragobj(2)" onmouseup="dropobj(2)" id="2" name="5" class="miniblock">Poll Voting [5]</div><div onmousedown="grabobj(3)" onmousemove="dragobj(3)" onmouseup="dropobj(3)" id="3" name="6" class="miniblock">SysAdmin Block [6]</div></TD></TR></TABLE>
```

and the below Javascript:

```
        window.instruct = function(id, instr){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.innerHTML = instr;
}

window.blockprefs = function(id, thisblock){
    // determine which slot thisblock belongs to
    s = id.getAttribute('SLOT');
    // identify all the child nodes associated to this slot
    c = id.childNodes;

        for(var i=1;i < c.length; i++) { // I set i = 1 here because I don't care about the parent element at this time.
        name = c[i].getAttribute('NAME');
//        console.log(c.length,c[i]);
        pos = document.getElementById('block_side'+name);
        ord = document.getElementById('block_order'+name);
        pos.setAttribute('VALUE',s);
        ord.setAttribute('VALUE',i);
        console.log(name,pos,ord,c[i]);
    }

};

window.grabobj = function(id){
//    console.log('moving object: '+id);
//    console.log(document.getElementById(id));
//    console.log(event.clientX+', '+event.clientY);
    thisblock = document.getElementById(id);
    thisblock.setAttribute('CLASS','moving');
    thisblock.setAttribute('STATUS','click');    
    thisblock.style.position = 'absolute';
    thisblock.style.left = event.pageX - 40; 
    thisblock.style.top = event.pageY - 20;
    //    id.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){console.log('moving mouse: x('+event.clientX)+') y('+event.clientY+')';},false);
};

window.drop = function(id, hit) {
id.setAttribute('STATUS','drop');                
id.setAttribute('CLASS','miniblock_unsaved');
id.setAttribute('STYLE','');
instruct('instruct','You have unsaved changes, be sure to commit your changes below.');
};

window.dropobj = function(id){
    thisblock = document.getElementById(id);
        if(thisblock.getAttribute('STATUS') == 'drag' || thisblock.getAttribute('STATUS') == 'click'){
            // determine if the block was dropped within one of the drop object targets
            // if it was not, return it to the original location, otherwise, drop it into the new location
            var left = document.getElementById("leftblocks"),
            right = document.getElementById('rightblocks'),
            leftbounds = left.getBoundingClientRect(),
            rightbounds = right.getBoundingClientRect(),
            t  = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            l = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

            if(event.clientX >= leftbounds.left &&  event.clientX <= leftbounds.right &&  event.clientY >= leftbounds.top &&  event.clientY <= leftbounds.bottom){
                // hit on the left blocks bounds, drop it into the left block
                left.appendChild(thisblock);
                //thisblock.insertBefore(left.firstchild);
                drop(thisblock);
                // now assign the hidden form element the correct values based on the current config in the left block then
                // here is what I think will have to happen:
                //  identify all child nodes of the parent node
                // identify all of the hidden form fields associated to those child nodes
                // update all of the hidden form fields associated to those child nodes with
                // the correct order and L / R flag.
                // not sure how to complete those tasks at this time.
//                console.log( document.getElementById('block_order' + thisblock.getAttribute('ID')));
//                console.log( left.childElementCount );
                blockprefs(left, thisblock);
        } else if(event.clientX >= rightbounds.left &&  event.clientX <= rightbounds.right &&  event.clientY >= rightbounds.top &&  event.clientY <= rightbounds.bottom){
                // hit on the right blocks bounds, drop it into the right block
                right.appendChild(thisblock);
                //thisblock.insertBefore(right.firstchild);
                drop(thisblock);
                // now assign the hidden form element the correct values based on the current config in the left block then
            } else {
                // user missed dropping into the left or right box, drop it back into unassigned.
                var u = document.getElementById("unassigned_blocks");
                u.appendChild(thisblock);
                drop(thisblock);
            }
    }
    };

window.dragobj = function(id){
    thisblock = document.getElementById(id);
if(thisblock.getAttribute('STATUS') == 'click' || thisblock.getAttribute('STATUS') == 'drag'){
    thisblock.style.left = event.pageX - 40; 
    thisblock.style.top = event.pageY - 20;
    thisblock.setAttribute('STATUS','drag');
    }
};



window.onload = function() {
// on mouseover change color of leftdiv or right div
var left = document.getElementById("leftblocks");
var right = document.getElementById('rightblocks');

console.log(left.nodeValue);


function block_over(block){ // set the attribute of the block on mouse over
//    console.log('setting property of block: '+block);
    block.setAttribute('CLASS','dropinto_over');
}
function block_out(block){ // set the attribute of the block on mouse out
    block.setAttribute('CLASS','dropinto');
}
left.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){block_over(left); },true); // listener to set the left block's attributes
left.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){block_out(left); },true);

right.addEventListener('mouseover',function(){block_over(right); },true); // listener to set the right block's attributes
right.addEventListener('mouseout',function(){block_out(right); },true);
};
```

I attempted to put this into a JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/vt1hcLL6/ but the frames were throwing it off so it might have to just go into a flat html file sorry.

As a user, the intent of this code is to be able to pick up the blocks and move them into the slots (either the left or the right side) blocks, or remove them from those blocks.
After doing so, javascript will set some values in the hidden form fields so that upon saving the page php will grab those values.
Currently it's only setup to do so if you move a block into the left side and yes once I get this all nailed from a hardcoded perspective I will abstract it further, for now some of this is hard coded.

My problem is that upon the first instance of dropping a block into the Left Side Block, everything works fine all the HIDDEN form fields update correctly with the SLOT="L" Attribute and the ORDER="i" attribute (i being the number corresponding to the child iteration.

Great! It works! Now... once a second block is added to that set from down below, the code breaks and I can't figure out why.

The code that is performing this functionality is in the blockprefs( ) function where I iterate through all the child nodes of the Left block and attempt to bring in the hidden form elements belonging to each child. I get a:
divblock.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: Nobody can take a stab at this? I thought I posed this question as appropriately as possible :)

Comment: Found it - the error was in the HTML HIDDEN elements with the NAME being inconsistent - caused in the php code that outputs this html. Fixed and it's working fine now.